# parse output and count number of times a string appears

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have some code running. Because of the complexity and the length I thought maybe use some code to make my life easy. So the code is running using `>commandA`

```
output
results
are
popping
...
here
```

I want to count the number of times `banana` appears in the output of `commandA` (which is running) and when the count is 10, I want to stop the processing (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and

```
echo "************we reached 10**********************"
```

and start again.

I am writing the code in perl on unix system.

EDIT: I cannot use grep function here as the command has already run. Or will be run but without a grep function. Before the command runs, I will turn on my program to look for the specific words in the terminal output. Now it would very easy to use grep, but I don't know which function in perl actually takes in the output to the terminal as stdin

Comment: Yep. You need to show some effort here.

Comment: `command | grep 'banana' | wc -l` ?

Comment: @Paulchenkiller: but how would that interactively terminate the process once `command | grep 'banana'| wc -l` reaches 10?

Comment: Its perl right? then use a global counter and `exit if $counter == 10`

Comment: how do i count??? I can't use grep as the command is already run...I am trying to write some code which can read what the output is

Comment: Store the output in a file while command is running (command needs to be running in background) and grep the file to count your pattern.

Comment: Start the other command in such a way that you can capture the output *and* know the PID (hint: make a pipe, `fork`, in the child: let the writing end of the pipe be the new STDOUT, then `exec` the target command). After that, count the output coming through the pipe. you can `kill TERM => $child_pid` whenever you like. Come back when you've tried this, and can show some code.

Comment: (you could also use the return value from `open` as a PID. Read the docs to learn more)

Comment: Paulchenkiller: How about `command | grep -c banana`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the other program by [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)ing a pipe from it to your Perl program, and then read its output line by line until you reach the terminating condition:

```perl
open my $pipe, 'commandA |'
    or die "Error opening pipe from commandA: $!\n";

my $n = 0;
while (<$pipe>) {
    $n++ if /banana/;
    last if $n >= 10;
}
close $pipe;  # kills the command with SIGPIPE if it's not done yet

print "commandA printed 'banana' ", ($n >= 10 ? "at least 10" : $n), " times.\n";
```

There are a couple of pitfalls to note here, though.  One is that closing the pipe will only kill the other program when it next tries to print something.  If the other program might run for a long time without generating any output, you may want to [`kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) it explicitly.

For this, you will need to know its process ID, but, conveniently, that's exactly what `open` returns when you open a pipe.  However, you may want to use the multi-arg version of `open`, so that the PID returned will be that of the actual commandA process, rather than of a shell used to launch it:

```perl
my $pid = open my $pipe, '-|', 'commandA', @args
    or die "Error opening pipe from commandA: $!\n";

# ...
kill 'INT', $pid;  # make sure the process dies
close $pipe;
```

Another pitfall is output buffering.  Most programs don't actually send their output directly to the output stream, but will buffer it until enough has accumulated or until the buffer is explicitly flushed.  The reason you don't usually notice this is that, by default, many programs (including Perl) will flush their output buffer at the end of every output line (i.e. whenever a `\n` is printed) *if* they detect that the output stream goes to an interactive terminal (i.e. a tty).

However, when you pipe the output of a program to another program, the I/O libraries used by the first program may notice that the output goes to a pipe rather than to a tty, and may enable more aggressive output buffering.  Often this won't be a problem, but in some problematic cases it could add a substantial delay between the time when the other programs prints a string and the time when your program receives it.

Unfortunately, if you can't modify the other program, there's not much you can easily do about this.  It *is* possible to replace the pipe with something called a "pseudo-tty", which looks like an interactive terminal to the other command, but that gets a bit complicated.  There's a CPAN module to simplify it a bit, though, called [IO::Pty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aPty).

(If you *can* modify the other program, it's a lot easier.  For example, if it's another Perl script, you can just add `$| = 1;` at the beginning of the script to enable output autoflushing.)

Comment: this is an amazing answer...can you please provide me with some sources which have this explained in more detail...its exactly what I want

Comment: [`perldoc perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) might be a good start, especially the "Pipe Opens" section. There's also some useful stuff in [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html). The `$|` variable is documented in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$|).

Comment: Hello I tried this...but it doesn't work...the process is finished way before I even get the chance to stop it. Isn't there anything which can actually control the flow of process with the pid. I mean, 23 banana's had crossed before it found that 10 were done. I am guessing pipe flows slower than the actual process

Comment: @Neil: It doesn't need a [`waitpid`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html), since the [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) already waits for the process to exit. However, output buffering in the other program, as well as the fact that the pipe itself is probably buffered, do meant that it's quite possible (and even likely) for the other program to keep running and producing quite a bit more input before your program even sees the tenth "banana", let alone gets around to killing the process and/or closing the pipe.